# Cómo puedo colocar la imagen a la izquierda en dispositivos de 900 px o mas

Tags: html, css, mediaqueries

estoy haciendo un artículo y no logro conseguir colocar la imagen a la izquierda al utilizar las medias query. Les comparto el código
(me dice que tengo que agregar más descripción para publicar)
Para la media query para dispositivos de pc utilizo un ancho mínimo de 900 pixeles y uso un display flex pero es como si el div con la clase card-image me seguiría manteniendo un display block.
Hola, estoy haciendo un artículo y no logro conseguir colocar la imagen a la izquierda al utilizar las medias query. Les comparto el código
(me dice que tengo que agregar más descripción para publicar)
Para la media query para dispositivos de pc utilizo un ancho mínimo de 900 pixeles y uso un display flex pero es como si el div con la clase card-image me seguiría manteniendo un display block.

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css");
*{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

:root{

    --off-white: #f5f5f5;
    --primary: #dd7373;

}

html{

    font-size: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}

.container{

    width: 80%;
    margin: 2rem auto;

}


.card{

    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    display: flex;

}

.card-image{

    height: 35rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.card-image img{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;

}

.card-content{

    padding: 2rem;

}

.blog-details,
.icon-text{

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.icon-text{

    margin-right: 1rem;

}       

.icon-text .icon{

    color: var(--primary);
    margin-right: 0.4rem;

}

.blog-cta{

    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}

.button-btn2{

    padding: 1.6rem 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 0.6rem;
    color: var(--off-white);
    text-decoration: none;

}

.share-button{

    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid var(--primary);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--primary);
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.share-button:focus{

    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: var(--off-white);

}

a{

    text-decoration: none;

}

button{

    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.icon-icon{display: block;}
body {

    background-color: #cccccc;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.6rem;

}
table {
    
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}

.main{

    background-color: #ffffff; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #4a4a4a;       

}

.two-columns{

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.two-columns .column {

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    
}

.button{

    background-color: #005fa7;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 22px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);


}

.button:hover{

    filter: none;

}

.two-columns.last{

    padding: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #007f9a;
    

}



.two-columns .content{

    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    

}

.two-columns .content p{

    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;

}

#facebook{

    filter: grayscale(100%);

}

#facebook:hover{

    filter: none;

}

#category1{

    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, filter 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease; /* Transiciones suaves para varios efectos */


}

#category1:hover{

    filter: none;

}


.tag{

    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #00954f;

}

h2{

    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #024b94;

}

#suscribirse:hover{

    color: #024b94;

}

.arrow-link {

    display: block;
  
}

p{

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h4,h5,h6{

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

}


.titulo{

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {

    .card{

        display: flex;
        height: 35rem;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    .card-image{

        height: auto;
        flex: 1;

    }

    .card-content{

        flex: 2;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

    }

}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="card">            

                <div class="card-image">

                    <img src="imagenes/imagen.jfif" alt="">
        
                </div>           

            <div class="card-content">

                <div class="blog-details">

                    <div class="icon-text">

                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="text">01/01/24</span>
             
                    </div>

                    <div class="icon-text">

                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="text">Autor</span>
             
                    </div>

                    <div class="icon-text">

                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="text">22</span>
             
                    </div>

                    <div class="icon-text">

                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="text">122</span>
             
                    </div>

                </div>

                <h2 class="blog-title">Informes TCA</h2>

                <p class="excerpt">Hola,aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

                <div class="blog-cta">

                    <a href="" class="button-btn2">Leer más</a>

                    <button class="share-button"><i class="bi bi-share-fill"></i></button>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: no puedo poner el codigo completo porque me dice que tengo que agregar mas descripcion

Comment: Era por el link del bootstrap.     <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
   El tema es que se me desconfiguro otras cosas

Comment: "Era por el link del bootstrap": ¿y cuál era realmente el problema?